# c++ initializing array of objects

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I need to split string to an array. And I get `object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I try to add new object to the array:

```
array<d3^> ^pr_d3; //d3 - class
parts = sr->ReadLine()->Split(
    (array<String^>^)nullptr, 
    StringSplitOptions::RemoveEmptyEntries); //array<String ^> ^parts;

pr_d3[0] = gcnew d3(
     parts[0], parts[1], 
     parts[2],
     Convert::ToInt16(parts[3]), Convert::ToInt16(parts[4])); //error
```

[Code on Ideon](http://ideone.com/e.js/ICZUGj)

Comment: @tobi303 The tag `C++` was wrong as this is actually `C++/CLI` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Comment: What is criteria of Split? Can u provide normal source code on ideone.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing the array `pr_d3`.

Removing the correct code, you currently have this:

```
array<d3^> ^pr_d3;
pr_d3[0] = gcnew d3(...);
```

The error is trying to access `[0]` of `pr_d3`, but `pr_d3` is still null.

You need to initialize `pr_d3` with `gcnew array<d3^>(<some array size>)`, or if you're not sure of the size you'll need, use a `List<d3^>` instead.